# Oracle SQL Stored Procedure missing expression error

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging, plsql

I am writing a stored procedure that is a dynamic sequel statement to write from one intermediate table to another table. I'm pretty new at writing sql and stored procedures especially. I tried add parameters within my statement but kept receiving this error: 
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06512: at "ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT", line 26
ORA-06512: at line 14
Process exited.
I took out the parameters and hardcoded in values to just try to get it to work but I'm still receiving the same errors.
Any suggestions?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                                                     
LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT 
(
P_SOURCE_DB IN VARCHAR2
, P_SOURCE_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
, P_TARGET_DB IN VARCHAR2
, P_TARGET_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
, P_COLUMN_NAME IN VARCHAR2
) AS 
l_sql_statement VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN


l_sql_statement :=
'INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP' || 
'(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, 
HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP) ' || 
' SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT' ||
', 1 as VERSION_SEQ' ||
', 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION' ||
', INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE' ||
', MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"' || 
', 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"' ||
', MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP' || --P_COLUMN_NAME ||              
' FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate ' || 
WHERE COLUMN_NM =' || ''||ROLE_TP||'' ||
'AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM =' || ''||C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP||'';
dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_statement);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement;
COMMIT;
END;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Did you try printing out the generated statement and running it, or just looking at it closely? Look at the line  `', SELECT MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"' || --FROM ` and the following line - that `SELECT` should not be there, it looks like a malformed subquery,,, though what you have won't even compile to get the error you describe.

Comment: here the parathenthesis `P_TARGET_TABLE.P_TARGET_TABLE) AS "SRC_ROWID"` .. what is the need of it ? and `from` why is commented

Comment: Sorry for that, the way looks in code on stackoverflow took my comment into the next line. I think i edited and fixed what you were seeing.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the where condition . remove the `||`

If you do a `dbms_output.putline();` you ll get the statment

To add the single quotes check the solution below

the reason of error:

```
INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP
  (PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
   VERSION_SEQ,
   TIMELINE_ACTION,
   LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
   SRC_ROWID,
   HUB_STATE_IND,
   ROLE_TP)
  SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT,
         1              as VERSION_SEQ,
         0              as TIMELINE_ACTION,
         INSERT_TS      as LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
         MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID",
         1              as "HUB_STATE_IND",
         MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP
    FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
   WHERE COLUMN_NM = || ROLE_TP ||
     AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = || C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP ||
```

The solution :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                                                     
LOOKUP_TABLE_INSERT 
(
P_SOURCE_DB IN VARCHAR2
, P_SOURCE_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
, P_TARGET_DB IN VARCHAR2
, P_TARGET_TABLE IN VARCHAR2
, P_COLUMN_NAME IN VARCHAR2
) AS 
l_sql_statement VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN


l_sql_statement :=
'INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP' || 
'(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, 
HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP) ' || 
' SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT' ||
', 1 as VERSION_SEQ' ||
', 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION' ||
', INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE' ||
', MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"' || 
', 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"' ||
', MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP' || --P_COLUMN_NAME ||              
' FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate ' || 
' WHERE COLUMN_NM =''' ||ROLE_TP||''     
' AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM =''' ||C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP|''' ';
dbms_output.put_line(l_sql_statement);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is correct as well. The dbms_output _line was something I didn't know about prior to this which would have been a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic statement your (edited) code generates is:

```
INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, 
HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)  SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, 1 as VERSION_SEQ, 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION, INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SELECT MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID", 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND", MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate  WHERE COLUMN_NM =||ROLE_TP|| AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM =||C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP||
```

or split onto multiple lines and annotated to show the issues it has:

```
INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ,
  TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)
SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT
, 1 as VERSION_SEQ
, 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION
, INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE
, SELECT MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"
--^^^^^^
, 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"
, MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP
FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
WHERE COLUMN_NM =||ROLE_TP|| AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM =||C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP||
--               ^^       ^^                    ^^                  ^^
```

You have a few problems with that; mostly that you have sets of `||` embedded in the generated statement in odd places, but also that you have an extra `SELECT`.

This might be closer to what you want, including escaped single quotes for your embedded string literals:

```
l_sql_statement :=
'INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP' || 
'(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP) ' || 
' SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT' ||
', 1 as VERSION_SEQ' ||
', 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION' ||
', INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE' ||
', MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"' || 
', 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"' ||
', MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP' ||
' FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate ' || 
' WHERE COLUMN_NM = ''ROLE_TP''' ||     
' AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = ''C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP''';
```

which generates (split again):

```
INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ,
  TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, SRC_ROWID, HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)
SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT
, 1 as VERSION_SEQ
, 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION
, INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE
, MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"
, 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"
, MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP
FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
WHERE COLUMN_NM = 'ROLE_TP'
AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = 'C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP'
```

You can split the string assignment across lines, which would simplify things a bit as it would reduce (or at the moment, remove) the string concatenation:

```
l_sql_statement :=
'INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP
(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
  SRC_ROWID, HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)
SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT
, 1 as VERSION_SEQ
, 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION
, INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE
, MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"
, 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"
, MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP
FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
WHERE COLUMN_NM = ''ROLE_TP''
AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = ''C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP''';
```

or you could use [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA) to avoid having to escape the single quotes.

When creating a dynamic statement, start with a valid static one and work backwards; and use `dbms_output` to display the final generated string so you can verify it and if necessary run it manually.

Of course, this doesn't need to be dynamic at all, but from your original question you intend to use the procedure arguments in a subquery at some point.

---

To use procedure parameters instead of the string literals you had to start with, you can concatenate those in:

```
l_sql_statement :=
'INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP
(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
  SRC_ROWID, HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)
SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT
, 1 as VERSION_SEQ
, 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION
, INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE
, MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"
, 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"
, MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP
FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
WHERE COLUMN_NM = ' || P_COLUMN_NAME || '
AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = ' || P_TARGET_TABLE;
```

or preferably use bind variables:

```
l_sql_statement :=
'INSERT INTO ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP
(PKEY_SRC_OBJECT, VERSION_SEQ, TIMELINE_ACTION, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
  SRC_ROWID, HUB_STATE_IND, ROLE_TP)
SELECT MISSING_VALUES AS PKEY_SRC_OBJECT
, 1 as VERSION_SEQ
, 0 as TIMELINE_ACTION
, INSERT_TS as LAST_UPDATE_DATE
, MISSING_VALUES as "SRC_ROWID"
, 1 as "HUB_STATE_IND"
, MISSING_VALUES as ROLE_TP
FROM ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate
WHERE COLUMN_NM = :COLUMN_NAME
AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = :TARGET_TABLE';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_statement USING P_COLUMN_NAME, P_TARGET_TABLE;
```

This still doesn't need to be dynamic though.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my issue. It has to be dynamic for when I add the variables in. However, in my WHERE clause I need it to be 'WHERE COLUMN_NM = 'ROLE_TP' AND LOOKUP_TBL_NM = 'C_S_LU_PTY_ROLE_TP' and im unsure of how to get those extra single quotes there.

Comment: @TheManC - I've added how to escape single quotes within a string.

Comment: This was so helpful and i greatly appreciate it. Does this change at all besides adding an extra single quote or two when adding in my variables?

Comment: You just need to be careful about how you concatenate in the table/column parameters and where you put the quotes.

Comment: I edited it, is that how it should look? It doesn't show up in the dbms_output, but I didn't know that existed before 5 minutes ago so im unsure of how that works.

Comment: Don't edit the question after it's been answered; the answers don't make sense any more... but no, that isn't right, and still doesn't need to be dynamic.

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed the question back to original.

Comment: It's all a learning experience *8-) I added how to do that part to my answer, but it's really getting too long and too far from the original issue. If your next step is to really do something dynamic, like using `P_SOURCE_TABLE` instead of the fixed `ECH_ETL_BATCH_ID.Ref_Intermediate`, then you do have to concatenate that in, in the same way and without quotes. If you get stuck on that though you should ask a new question showing your code and errors at that point.